# How many subsets of size L do not contain the first k arbitrary pairs?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let there be a large set $X$, and a bijective function $f$ which maps the integer range 1 to $|X| \choose 2$  onto the subsets of $X$ of size 2. Given integers $L$ and $k$, where $2 \leq L \leq |X|$ and $1 \leq k \leq {|X| \choose 2}$, what is the cardinality of the collection $P^L_k=\{Y : Y \subset X$ and $|Y|=L$ and $f(i) \not\subset Y \; \forall 1\leq i \leq k\}$.

Is there a more efficient way than generating all subsets of size $L$ and checking? Alternatively, do you see a good way to approximate the cardinality?

Comment: Is f given as part of input or some fixed function you forgot to specify in the question?  If f is given as part of input, then the problem is equivalent to counting the independent sets of certain size in a graph, and I am sure that it is #P-complete although I do not have a reference at hand.

Comment: Yes the function f is given. How would you construct such a graph?

Comment: Rephrasing the current question in terms of counting independent sets of certain size in a graph is an easy exercise, so probably it is better if you can think it by yourself.  Please ask me (or someone else) if you cannot figure it out in a day or two.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Hmm this is bad news, literature seems to say that it is very hard to even approximate unless the graph is very sparse.